# Calling a method from a common library - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.1
```

in my lib/assets, I have a gloabl_helper.rb with the following in it:

```
def current_user_is_admin
  if current_user.try(:role?)
    if current_user.role == 'admin'
      return TRUE
    end
  end
  return 0
end
```

And in my view, I have the following:

```
<% if current_user_is_admin == TRUE %>
<% end %>
```

When I try running the app, I get the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user_is_admin' for #<#<Class:0x0000000667deb8>:0x00000004fef818>
```

Is this a change in Rails4? I understand that I should put helper methods in the helper scripts, but some of the helpers apply globally and such should be in the lib/assets folder. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Why don't you put it in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`? 2. If you insist, did you make sure that `lib/assets` is autoloaded by Rails (and why assets?)? 3. You need to pass current_user to this method anyway unless you define it in `ApplicationController`

Comment: I am using Devise, so current_user is globally available. I did however forget to include lib and lib/assets in application.rb, like this:     config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

Comment: Apparently, this is not working (autoloading)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- why is there a `TRUE`
- why is there a `0`
- you don't need `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"`
- what is the "helper"? a module?
- did you include the "helper"
- `current_user` is not globally available. it's mixed into your `ApplicationController`

write ideomatic ruby code

```
def current_admin?
  return unless logged_in?
  current_user.role == 'admin'
end
```

Comment: The actual method code I posted is after I experimented for a while, so it's not the primary issue. Helper is a module and no I did not include it in the application controller as I thought that this was not required if it's autoloaded. I am not sure I understand what you mean by current_user is not globally available. I thought it was available from every controller/view/model. Including the file in the application controller does solve the undefined method or variable error

Comment: all files in `autoload_paths` are "loaded" for your rails application and rails will re-load them during development, that is all. if you have functionality, that you want to USE, you need to DO something with it, like including it into your classes. that's also what i mean by "not globaly available", ie you don't have those methods in your models, because they are included in your ApplicaitonController